# how to create cells in flex(have to find each cell)

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

can any one help me how to make cells in flex....

Suppose if i need 4 columns and 10 rows...it should display grid with rows and columns.

And i should be able to find each cell.

Answer (score 0):

It depends. If you need a table-like component you can use the mx:Datagrid component or if you have custom component which you want to repeat you can use the s:Datagroup (Repeater in Flex3) with a Tile layout. You can use getElementAt() to get the cell.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply....

I want elaborate more on this....right now i am working on scheduler

i need table for days and times...if i want schedule for particular
day and particular   time ...i should be able to click that particular cell...and i should know the cell where it is...